# How do I POST to a Google Cloud Storage bucket via API

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm attempting to do a `POST` to a bucket via API. I have an API key, and I have a client-id and secret. What should be included in the header for authentication to my bucket for a simple post?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do a `POST` with the [RESTful](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/) API you should add an `"Authorization: Bearer [OAUTH2_TOKEN]"`. I recommend on following the Quickstart on [Uploading Objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) with Rest API which guides you on how to achieve this and searching the [OAuth 2.0 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to get the Token

Taken from the guide:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @[OBJECT] \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer [OAUTH2_TOKEN]" \
    -H "Content-Type: [OBJECT_CONTENT_TYPE]" \
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/[BUCKET_NAME]/o?uploadType=media&name=[OBJECT_NAME]"
```

Comment: I followed your instructions and I was able to do a post with the bearer token. However it was only temporary. Is there a way to make it so the Bearer OAUTH2 token doesn't change?